# 14.04 or 15.04 for an ultrabook

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, desktop-environments

I was asked to help choose the DE for an ultrabook. I'm considering the following ones for the time being

- KDE
- Gnome Shell
- Unity
- Cinnamon

Cinnamon is shipped by Linux Mint, not Ubuntu, so we will neglect this DE.

I'd rather stick with an LTS release unless there are reasons to choose a non-LTS variant.
So the question follows: did any changes significant for an ultrabook usage occur in between, so that it would be reasonable to resign from the 14.04 release and choose 15.04?

(A little off-topic, so for discussion in comments: is there any other DE which would be a good choice for an ultrabook?)

Answer (score 0):

No significant changes occurred after 14.04.2 LTS so you can go for it. Tough GNOME is stable, I would still prefer the Unity interface. If you have a good Internet connection, I would suggest you to download multiple ISO files.

Comment: 14.04.x uses gnome 3.10 and 15.04 - 3.16. Were there no significant changes between the Gnome releases?

Comment: It uses the unity interface by default. I recommend installing Ubuntu MATE only if you want to stick to a GNOME base.

Comment: Ubuntu GNOME uses the Gnome Shell in contrast to normal Ubuntu which uses Unity.